# Download option disabled for lambda functions in vscode

Tags: aws-lambda

I have authenticated myself onto the AWS toolkit extension and I also see my functions in Explorer. What could be the reason for not being able to download a function to work locally?
Here is the snip-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue. When using Node 20.x, the button appears to be disabled. However, after creating another Lambda with Node 18.x, I was able to download the file. I haven't been able to identify the exact cause of this behavior, but I hope this information proves helpful to you.

Best regards,
Fernando

Comment: Any update on this ?? Why is this odd behavior seen lately. Thanks

Comment: I believe that The last update in the visual code caused it. I'm not sure about it but I have another similar problem with the last version of vscode and the connection by ssh to the one server.

Comment: I use AWS cloud9 and the same issue still persists, Now I am just creating my new lambda functions using node18x instead of 20x. My guess at this point is the cloud9's python version might be mismatching or not compatible with node20x.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same situation and after read Fernando's comment I solved my problem by applying the change in the version from python 3.12 to python 3.10.